# Javascript- Order of script execution

Tags: javascript, html, download, load

I have read questions but I am not able to find answers related to my issue. I have the following code:

```
<script>
        var pText = "";
        var firstText = document.getElementById("firstText");
        pText += 'appear first';
        firstText.innerHTML = pText;
</script>
<script>
        var qText = "";
        var secondText = document.getElementById("secondText");
        qText += 'appear next';
        secondText.innerHTML = qText;
</script>

<div class="card text-center">
  <div class="card-header">
    <h1>title</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <span id="firstText"></span>
    <span id="secondText"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Due to the ordering of the script, I was expecting the result to be:

```
appear first
appear next
```

However the ordering is:

```
appear next
appear first
```

I have looked into `defer` and `sync` but I am not very sure how I would be able to use the properties. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: baseed on the code you give, i expect that you should get error: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null and i tested,i got error.So,please show the true order you run

Comment: I would expect both to appear at the same time because of how browsers schedule rendering - seriously, if you can *see* one lot of text appear before the other, you either have extremely good eyesight, or an extremely slow computer (of course, the script tags need to be BELOW the html for anything to display at all as per previous comment) - I suspect *actual code* is far removed from code you presented in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what async/defer do when used with script tags, so I'll leave that to someone else if that's really what you want to do.

If all you're looking for is to control the order these chunks of script (or your actual script if these are only theoretical) are executed you can put each chunk of script in a function, attach an event listener to [document.DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) and have the handler run them ASAP after the window loads. Then you could call, for example, `appearFirst(); appearNext();` inside the event handler, and you'll know how it's going to be run.